# How to convert a hex char to binary in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, binary, hex

I am trying to convert two (2) inputs from the user.
I am taking input in variable `M`. The `K` variable is unused.

I tried to solve it using `for` loop, but, I could not do it. The first loop could not stop.

Is it wrong to use an array?
And, can I use `for` loop after to input the binary output into a new array?

Here's my code:

```
include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char M[64],K[64];
    long int i=0;

    cout<<"Enter M: ";
    cin>>M;
    cout<<"M= ";

    while(M[i])
    {
        switch(M[i])
        {
        case '0':
            cout<<"0000";
            break;
        case '1':
            cout<<"0001";
            break;
        case '2':
            cout<<"0010";
            break;
        case '3':
            cout<<"0011";
            break;
        case '4':
            cout<<"0100";
            break;
        case '5':
            cout<<"0101";
            break;
        case '6':
            cout<<"0110";
            break;
        case '7':
            cout<<"0111";
            break;
        case '8':
            cout<<"1000";
            break;
        case '9':
            cout<<"1001";
            break;
        case 'A':
            cout<<"1010";
            break;
        case 'B':
            cout<<"1011";
            break;
        case 'C':
            cout<<"1100";
            break;
        case 'D':
            cout<<"1101";
            break;
        case 'E':
            cout<<"1110";
            break;
        case 'F':
            cout<<"1111";
            break;
        case 'a':
            cout<<"1010";
            break;
        case 'b':
            cout<<"1011";
            break;
        case 'c':
            cout<<"1100";
            break;
        case 'd':
            cout<<"1101";
            break;
        case 'e':
            cout<<"1110";
            break;
        case 'f':
            cout<<"1111";
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"nInvalid hexadecimal digit "<<M[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
    cout<<"\nEnter K: ";
    cin>>K;
    cout<<"K: ";
    while(K[i])
    {
        switch(K[i])
        {
        case '0':
            cout<<"0000";
            break;
        case '1':
            cout<<"0001";
            break;
        case '2':
            cout<<"0010";
            break;
        case '3':
            cout<<"0011";
            break;
        case '4':
            cout<<"0100";
            break;
        case '5':
            cout<<"0101";
            break;
        case '6':
            cout<<"0110";
            break;
        case '7':
            cout<<"0111";
            break;
        case '8':
            cout<<"1000";
            break;
        case '9':
            cout<<"1001";
            break;
        case 'A':
            cout<<"1010";
            break;
        case 'B':
            cout<<"1011";
            break;
        case 'C':
            cout<<"1100";
            break;
        case 'D':
            cout<<"1101";
            break;
        case 'E':
            cout<<"1110";
            break;
        case 'F':
            cout<<"1111";
            break;
        case 'a':
            cout<<"1010";
            break;
        case 'b':
            cout<<"1011";
            break;
        case 'c':
            cout<<"1100";
            break;
        case 'd':
            cout<<"1101";
            break;
        case 'e':
            cout<<"1110";
            break;
        case 'f':
            cout<<"1111";
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"nInvalid hexadecimal digit "<<K[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. Then, please form short, complete sentences, with a capital letter at the beginning and a period at their end. Your initial text is nearly unreadable because there is zero indication where one statement ends and the next one starts.

Comment: Remove the `return 0;` between the M and K loops.

Comment: So what doesn't work? When I run your code it seems to work fine. http://cpp.sh/3h7xa

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you are using 2 parts of the code, repetitively, you should consider using a function for higher scalability (Imagine if you wanted to convert 5 inputs, it is not a good practice to copypaste the switch 5 times.

Then, the for loop is mostly used for known sized collections, and the while for unknown sized ones, so for the for you can just put the size of your array:

```
for(int i = 0;i<64;i++){
  convert(M[i]);
}
```

If you want to have a good scalability you should consider using sizeof(M)/sizeof char or things like a global constant or #define for the maximun string you can have...

Hope it helped.